# How to select data from table with multiple where on the same column based on another table in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a posts table, each post has tags, each tag has a topic, for example:

```
Post name: Anything
Post tag: 1, 2, 3

1: is the id of Male
2: is the id of United States
3: is the id of India
```

The `1` tag belongs to the gender topic, the `2` and `3` tags belong to the country topic.

The tables here are like this:

```
posts:
 - id
 - name

tags:
 - id
 - name
 - topic_id

topics:
 - id
 - name

tags_posts:
 - tag_id
 - post_id
```

Now I want to do a filter like this if the user selected Male and the United States on the UI so I should select all posts that have Male and the United States tags.

```
SELECT * FROM posts where tag_relation = Male and tag_relation = United States

tag_relation here means JOIN to tags_posts table
```

But if the user selected Male, United States, and India on the UI so I should select all posts that have Male and (United States or India) tags.

```
SELECT * FROM posts where tag_relation = Male and (tag_relation = United States or tag_relation = India)

tag_relation here means JOIN to tags_posts table
```

As you can see if the tags belong to the same topic the where should be `OR` but if they belong to the different topics so the where should be `AND`.

So the question here is how I can join the topic tables and check if the selected tags are the same topic and group the selected tags based on the topic then do the where based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  You can count the topics that match each post and then compare that to the number of topics in the provided tags.  Here is one method that returns the post ids:

```
select tp.post_id
from tags t join
     tags_posts tp
     on tp.tag_id = t.id 
where t.tag in ( . . . ) -- the list here
group by tp.post_id
having count(distinct t.topic_id) = (select count(distinct t2.topic_id)
                                     from tags t
                                     where t2.tag in ( . . . )  -- the list here
                                    );
```

You can join to the `posts` table to get other columns (or use `exists` or `in` or whatever).

You can do this using window functions as well.  However, `count(distinct)` is not supported, so you can use the `dense_rank()` sum method instead:

```
select tp.post_id
from (select t.*,
             (-1 +
              dense_rank() over (order by t.topic_id asc) +
              dense_rank() over (order by t.topic_id desc)
             ) as num_topics
      from tags t
      where t.tag in ( . . . )
     ) t join
     tags_posts tp
     on tp.tag_id = t.id 
group by tp.post_id, t.num_topics
having count(distinct t.topic_id) = t.num_topics
```

Comment: You are selecting the tags, I want to select the posts based on tags, also the `in` clause will not work here because not all tags belongs to the same topic

Comment: @MohamedHamdan . . . This is selecting the posts, not the tags.

Comment: posts are in posts table, the `tags_posts` is for relation only because the relation between the tags and posts is many to many, so the posts are in `posts` table and the relation between posts and tags are in `tags_posts` table

Comment: @MohamedHamdan . . . The `post_id` should be fine.  You can get the additional columns using a `join` or whatever.  That doesn't seem central to your question.

Comment: It seems to be working, tested it and so far it return what I need, I need to test it more, can you explain what you did?